# Is it possible to make custom mobs spawn the same way as regular mobs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to make custom mobs spawn in the world like usual mobs? BTW I am in 1.12

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Can you clarify it?

Comment: @Frank He wants to add custom mobs to Minecraft's spawning algorithm.

Comment: @Bearsta - do you have a custom mob that you wish to make spawn? What attempts have you made so far to make them spawn?

Comment: @aytimothy I don't think that's quite it; look at the original version, pre-edit.

Comment: Dont you mean spawn a custom mob with a spawn egg?

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you could try placing daylight sensors and switching them to night mode, then linking that to a command block that spawns a custom mob.

You could place that contraption in multiple places around the map.